# Barometer gem: use latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using [barometer gem](https://github.com/attack/barometer/).

I have a model with :latitude and :longitude defined, but the docs don't specify the use of latitude and longitude for a query.

I've got this so far

```
barometer = Barometer.new(:latitude, :longitude) #does not work
weather = barometer.measure

puts weather.current.temperature
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't ever worked with Barometer gem, but from documentation I suggest you use such snippet

```
coordinates = "40.756054,-73.986951"
barometer = Barometer.new(coordinates)
```